# Regex declared in find and replace module won't correctly access the match

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

So i've got a regex in vscode that matches any sentence after the first `{space}` using `(?<=\s).*` per line.

Here's a screenshot of what the regex is matching.

[image]

I'm trying to convert a txt file consisting of over 50,000 lines of un-formatted objects to correct json by placing all the text elements inside strings. So i'm using the find and replace feature to first match the text elements and then individually place them inside `""` using the replace module in vscode.

[image]

However when I use `$0` in the replace module. It seems the `$0` strangely it captures all words past the second found space, rather then the first found space.

[image]

You see the issue? Everything looks to be replacing accordingly until you look here.

[image]

This occurs for any sentences that are actually spaced out rather then connecting with `-`

I have no clue why this is the case. My guess is I need to reformat my regex somehow inside `()`, because to my knowledge, the `$` method of calling regex expressions declared in the find module only captures the regex expressions between the defined brackets?

Here's a sample of the txt document.

```
"Type": language
"Subtag": ht
"Description": Haitian
"Description": Haitian Creole
"Added": 2005-10-16
"Suppress": Latn
%%
"Type": language
"Subtag": hu
"Description": Hungarian
"Added": 2005-10-16
"Suppress": Latn
%%
"Type": language
"Subtag": hy
"Description": Armenian
"Added": 2005-10-16
"Suppress": Armn
"Comments": see also hyw
%%
"Type": language
"Subtag": hz
"Description": Herero
"Added": 2005-10-16
%%
"Type": language
"Subtag": ia
"Description": Interlingua (International Auxiliary Language Association)
"Added": 2005-10-16
%%
"Type": language
"Subtag": id
"Description": Indonesian
"Added": 2005-10-16
"Suppress": Latn
"Macrolanguage": ms
%%
"Type": language
"Subtag": ie
"Description": Interlingue
"Description": Occidental
"Added": 2005-10-16
%%
"Type": language
"Subtag": ig
"Description": Igbo
"Added": 2005-10-16
```

I'm sure this is quite a specific and uncommon issue, so thanks in advance.

**Update**

I forgot to mention I'm using the javascript regex flavor.

Past solution seemed to only work for PHP and not javascript.

[image]

Comment: My best guess is that you should use `$1` instead of `$0`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I already tried `$1` with no luck. It appears the issue isn't with the replace module but rather how I'm formatting my regex expression in the find module to cater for the replace module.

Comment: Can you post a few lines of sample code you want to replace, in code format, so we can try on our system

Comment: Actually, for this task I would not use any look ahead / behind. I would just match the line with something like `^([^:]*:\s)(.*)` and then replace it with something like `$1"$2"`...

Comment: Okay I added a sample of the txt document if that helps. I tried to past your solution in find and replace virolino, and it wouldn't load any matches. Can you try this yourself and confirm it works? Sounds like you might be on to it.

Comment: I tested it here without modification: https://regex101.com/r/wBv69J/1/ It seems to work...

Comment: Oh I see what's happening. I forgot to mention I'm using the regex flavor native to javascript. That's a PHP regex and won't match for javascript. Even though we're working with a txt file, my IDE regex is javascript.

Comment: Tested with ECMAScript / Javascript: https://regex101.com/r/wBv69J/2 I do not see any problem.

Comment: I clicked on that exact link and everything is matched. I'll send it as a screenshot in the main question so you can see.

Comment: Perhaps without the ^ and $, the multiline matching may be different.

Comment: I updated the answer. Yes, without ^ and $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [**tested**](https://regex101.com/r/wBv69J/1/) it with the following regex:

```
^([^:]*:\s)(.*)
```

and with the following replace sting:

```
$1"$2"
```

It seems to do the job.

---

[This](https://regex101.com/r/wBv69J/3) seems to work better with Javascript:

```
([^:]*:\s)(.*)
```

Same replace string.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: If you need to do it once (or a few times), and the data is not several giga-bytes, then just use regex101.com, it will do the job for you.

Comment: And what do you mean "the same"? I posted screenshots that is works, at least on regex101.com

Comment: My bad, I made a typo. You're right this updated expression works. Thanks a lot for your help, and time! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have VSCode installed at the moment either, but does this work? On the first capture group?

```
^.*?\s(.*$)
```

Can try installing VSCode if not.

Removing the ^ and $ may affect results also (start, end line matches in single versus multiline modes).